# sql select question

Tags: sql, select

I have 4 tables;

- articles
- machines
- features
- required features

the problem is that articles can be produced on machines but only on the machines that have the features that are required by the articles.
a product can require 0 or more features and a machine can have 0 or more features

I want to create a query that shows a complet overview of valid article-machine combinations.
the question is: How can I do that?

Below is an example data set for MySQL. it should result in the following query result:

```
"car";"virtual machine"
"boat";"virtual machine"
"boat";"lean machine"
```

here's the dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `articles` (`name`) VALUES
('car'),
('boat');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `features` (
  `machine` text NOT NULL,
  `feature_name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `features` (`machine`, `feature_name`) VALUES
('lean machine', 'punch'),
('virtual machine', 'punch'),
('virtual machine', 'drill');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `machines` (
  `name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `machines` (`name`) VALUES
('lean machine'),
('virtual machine');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `required_features` (
  `article` text NOT NULL,
  `feature` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `required_features` (`article`, `feature`) VALUES
('car', 'drill'),
('boat', 'punch');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you provide, the solution is just a few joins - but I'm assuming that it's possible for an article to require more than one feature, and for a machine to have one of those features, but not all the features required.

In this case, you would need to also make sure that a machine that has a matching feature of an article also doesn't lack any other features required by the article.  I don't think a left join would do the job because it would then return the machine for the matching feature, and the null for the non-matching feature... whereas it shouldn't return the machine at all in this case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.name,
    m.name
FROM
    articles a INNER JOIN
    required_features rf ON rf.article = a.name INNER JOIN
    features f ON f.feature_name = rf.feature INNER JOIN
    machines m 
        ON m.name = f.machine
        -- Make sure that there is no feature required that isn't provided by the machine.
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM 
                machines m2 INNER JOIN
                features f2 ON f2.machine = m2.name LEFT JOIN
                required_features rf2 ON rf2.feature = f2.feature_name
            WHERE 
                m2.name = m.name AND
                rf2.feature IS NULL
                AND rf2.article = a.name
        )
```

Comment: I would like to do so, but I couldn't validate the answer yet as the query contains a couple of errors. one I was not able to solve yet; a.name is not known

Comment: @Michael; the a.name on line 16 is an unknown column. I guess that that is because a is in the outer query. How should I change the query?

Comment: It looks like you figured it out by moving the a.name to the where clause... thanks for fixing that issue...

Answer (score 2):

It's just a couple of joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.article, f.machine
FROM articles AS a
INNER JOIN required_features AS rf
    ON rf.article = a.article
INNER JOIN features AS f
    on f.feature_name = rf.feature
```

This will give you all valid combinations of article and machine as related through those tables.  You could get away with one `JOIN` probably since the `articles` table is unneeded for this query - just select `article` from the `required_features` table and join to `features`.

If you want more info, you could change the last join to a `LEFT JOIN`, and a `NULL` value for `f.machine` would tell you that the article can't currently be produced.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from articles ar
join required_features rf on rf.article=ar.name
join features f on f.feature_name=rf.feature
join machines m on m.name=f.machine
```

Comment: `SELECT *` will return a lot more fields than requested in the OP